# How can Update this state using React useState hook Button click

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I try to update my react state using useState hook .

```
const [Combine, setCombine] = useState([{
makeTeacher:'', makeSub:''}])
```

*Here I hook define *

```
 {Teacher && Subject ?<button onClick={()=>showStatus(Teacher,Subject)}>save</button>:null }
```

*if Teacher and subject are available then *

```
 const showStatus = (t,s) => {
 setCombine( t, s)
 console.log(Combine) }
```

*My Desier Result is *
[0] index makeTeacher:'t', makeSub:'s'

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: [0] index makeTeacher:'t', makeSub:'s'

Comment: You can do `setCombine([{ makeTeacher: t, makeSub: s }])`

Comment: THis not working sir ..

Comment: Can you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on codesandbox?

Comment: https://oyw37z.csb.app/

Comment: Yep. This is expected. When you update the state, it won't be available in the same function immediately due to closures. `setState` updates the state and triggers a re-render of the component. During the re-render, you will be able to access the latest value. Try moving console log outside of the update function. You will first see the old value and then finally, the new value.

Answer (score -1):

setState is asynchrone.

Do this to have updated values in the console

```
useEffect(()=>{
 console.log(combine) 
}, combine)
const showStatus = (t,s) => setCombine( t, s)
```

Currently, your console.log shows an outdated version of the state